# Clean-code way to handle conditional import in Python

Tags: python, import

I am working with a function where depending on the user's input different modules are imported, e.g.

```
user_choice = 1

if user_choice==1:
  import module1
if user_choice==2:
  import module2
```

This choice then feeds into my function (let's call it `fun`) to affect the output. I would ideally like to write these imports into the function (or some external function) because I want the user to be able to supply `user_choice` as an argument - this would be ideal in terms of clean-code.

```
def fun(..., user_choice):
  if user_choice==1:
    import module1
  if user_choice==2:
    import module2
  ...
```

Now, `fun` doesn't take much time to run, but will be run many times. My understanding is that `import` works such that the imported module remains cached (that is, accessible) even once the function has completed its first run, but import is nevertheless expensive and slow.

Does a better flow exist? For instance, is there a fast way of checking whether a module has already been imported and importing it only if it hasn't? How do you more experienced Python engineers deal with this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `import module1` / `import module2` at the global level?  You can call `module1.render()` or `module2.render()` as the choice demands.

Comment: @TimRoberts they're pretty large modules so it's not ideal (working memory-wise) to import both if the user will only ever be using one or the other. In other words, some people may freely switch between both because they have enough working memory to do so, but for others it'd be a problem

Comment: @TimRoberts I can't seem to find any documentation on ```module.render()``` in Python, can you elaborate a little on what it does and how it solves the problem?

Comment: I made that up.  I assume your module is currently doing something global when you import it.  A better plan is to have the module have everything inside of a function, which you can call at any time.